HTML range input show max level reached but still showing space left
HTML ranger dom element set the min=0 and max=100; when reached to the max, 100, the bar is still slightly short, per the image attached.
How can this be filled properly up to the end of the bar?
Ranger input at 100%
Bootstrap v3.3.7, the "form-control" class is affecting this.
How do I adjust the CSS styles to revert this?
here is the sample HTML code
<input type='text' class="form-control" id="html_ranger" name="html_ranger" />


@TimRoberts <input type="range">

Can you show us your HTML?  I can't duplicate this issue.

If you want a CSS answer, wouldn't adding the css tag also make sense?
